# Google Analytics API sampling

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I'm trying to pull up my goals against campaigns data through Google Analytics CORE-API. However, when I do so, one of my campaigns simply disappears. It only shows in the interface report or when I download it through excel. Can sampling exclude a campaign from the report? Is the sampling effect higher when using API? Will upgrading to GA premium and using the Measurement-API eliminates this effect? Thank you!